# Angularjs: otherwise of $routerProvider not working in Child modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I have the following structure for my angular app.

Parent Module->Child Module

In the parent Module, I have defined states as follows:

```
$urlRouterProvider
        .otherwise('/home');

        $stateProvider
          .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
            })
          .state('state1', {
                url: '/state1',
                templateUrl: 'views/state1.html'
            })
            .state('state2', {
             url: '/state2',
             templateUrl: 'views/state2.html'    
            })
```

In the Child module I have defined it as follows:

```
$urlRouterProvider
        .otherwise('/child/childstate1');

        $stateProvider

          .state('child', {
                url: '/child',
                templateUrl: 'views/child.html',
                abstract: true
            })
            .state('child.childstate1', {
             url: '/childstate1',
             templateUrl: 'views/childstate1'
            })
             .state('child.childstate2', {
             url: '/childstate2',
             templateUrl: 'views/childstate2'
            })
```

So I want the app(by default) redirect to */child/childstate1* when in childmodule and redirect to */home* when in the parent module other than childmodule.
When I try to access */child* I am redirected to */home*. I overcame this issue by using:

```
.when('/child', '/child/childstate1')
.when('/child/', '/child/childstate1')
```

It is a working hack but the issue arises when I try to access */child/random* It redirects to */home* but instead it should redirect to */child/childstate1*

Comment: what module do you load? the parent module or the child?

Comment: @Zamboney   I load the parent module and try to go to Child module by _/child_ , it redirects me to _/home_. If I am in Child module and go to _/child/random/_ , it redirects to _/home_.